# How do I check for the presence of a valid email (digital) signature attached to an Outlook MailItem (email message)?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Is there any way to

1. Retrieve a digital signature attached to a MailItem using VBA?
2. Verify its validity using VBA?

I'm pretty much limited to VBA in this regard.  I've tried inspecting the Sender and MailItem objects but I can't see anything about a Signature object.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104680/adding-a-default-signature-to-outlook-email-vba help? Just to clarify, are you referring to an HTML signature snippet, or a digital signature for secure e-mail? (As described here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/secure-messages-with-a-digital-signature-HP001230539.aspx)

Comment: The latter - I'm not looking for some text at the bottom of the message, but a signature verifying that the email was truly sent from the sender.

Comment: Gotcha. You might check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299120/outlook-vba-messageclass-save-digital-signature

Answer (score 0):

Outlook always represents signed/encrypted messages as regular `"IPM.Note MailItem"` objects. It goes as far as returning a fake `IMessage` MAPI interface from the `MailItem.MAPIOBJECT` property.

You can see this in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - select a signed message, click IMessage button on the OutlookSpy ribbon. PR_MESSAGE_CLASS will be IPM.Note. Select the PR_ENTRYID property, right click, select IMAPISession::OpenEntry. You will get back the real message with `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS` = `IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned`. You can see the attachment that contains the data.

You are pretty much limited to Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author - any language - it wraps Extended MAPI) if you want to distinguish signed/encrypted message from the regular ones. Redemption exposes [RDOEncryptedMessage](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoencryptedmessage.htm) object. You can retrieve it from `RDOSession.GetMessageFromID` using the entry id retrieved from `MailItem.EntryID` property in OOM.